# Can't send navParams from two separate pages to another page in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

```
itemTapped($event, customer) {
    let customerData = { customer };
    this.navCtrl.push(AddInvoicesPage, { customerData});
}
```

This is where i'm setting the navParams.

```
this.customer = this.navParams.get("customerData");
```

way of access to navparams.The problem is "this.customer" is undefined! How can i solve this issue?

Comment: what do you by sending from 2 separate pages? you only arrive at the page form one of the multiple pages.

Comment: Found a solution yet?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512464/multiple-executions-of-page-constructor-using-navparams?noredirect=1#comment76020868_44512464

Answer (score 0):

An object has to have key and value. So try this `this.navCtrl.push(AddInvoicesPage, { customerData: theDataYouWantToSend });`

Comment: The same goes for creating an object, `let customerData = { customer };` doesn't look right. Try `let customerData = { data: customer };`.

Comment: still getting the same error.when I using this.navCtrl.push(AddInvoicesPage, customer ); for setting the params and for access the data this.customer = this.navParams.data; its's working.but the problem is when I'm setting navParams from two separate pages,It will override the other object.can you suggest a better way to do that?

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean.

Comment: I'm trying to send two separate data from two pages to another page using navParams.When I'm using the code like below it's working but cannot access to the data separately.For set data>>>>this.navCtrl.push(AddInvoicesPage, customer );<<< For access data>>>> this.customer = this.navParams.data;<<<< How can I access to the each data object separately ???

Comment: You can only send data from the page you are navigating from. Maybe your situation calls for a [service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html)?

Answer (score 0):

If you send like this:

```
this.navCtrl.push(AddInvoicesPage, { customerData: customerData});
```

You can get like this:

```
this.navparams.data.customerData
```