# multiple executions of page constructor using navParams

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I need to search customers and items from add-invoice page.For that I have created two separate pages call customer-search and item-search.When I search the customer I have to go to the customer-search page and come back to the add-invoice page with customer detail.After that in the same same way I have to go to the item-search page multiple times for get multiple items and come back to the add-invoice page with items details.

To do that task,I'm passing navParams from the two pages to add-invoice page.

set navParams in customer-search page

```
itemTapped($event, customer) {
  this.navCtrl.push(AddInvoicesPage, { customerData: customer });
}
```

set navParams in item-search page

```
itemTapped($event, item) {
  this.navCtrl.push(AddInvoicesPage, { itemData: item });
}
```

access to the navParams in add-invoice page

```
this.customer = this.navParams.get('customerData');
this.item = this.navParams.get('itemData');
```

When I'm accessing the data separately It works.But the problem is, when I'm accessing the `itemData` after accessing the `customerData`, `customerData` will become "undefined".In the same way `itemData` will become undefined, when I'm accessing `customerData` after accessing `itemData`.

I just need to access to both `customerData`,`itemData` in the same time.What is the most suitable way to overcome this problem! Give me the best suggestion.Thank you!

Comment: "I just need to access to both `customerData,itemData` in the same time."
What do you mean by this? If you route to `AddInvoicesPage` from `customer-search page` then only `customerData` available from `navParams`. same way If you route to `AddInvoicesPage` from `item-search page` then only `itemData` available from `navParams`

Comment: As of now, you will another set of problems by doing this way. The previous page data that you get will be null. which will causes unexpected behaviour. The other case you can use to solve this dilema is using ionicstoragemodule